# How to show subdomain on subfolder (IIS)

Tags: iis, proxy, subdomain, directory

I have a website named: www.website.com
And I have an application named: application.website.com

Those are on different servers.

And now.
I want to show application.website.com on www.website.com/application.
But not with iframe. And includes all sub url's. 
(For example application.website.com/try.html --> www.website.com/application/try.html)

How can that be possible?
Is that possible with Reverse Proxy? If it is, is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reverse proxy for that; something to put in front of both servers, that will intercept requests and for www.website.com and forward those to the main server, *unless* they are for www.website.com/application, in which case case it will forward them to the second server.

Any reverse proxy will do, on Windows you can use [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). The old ISA/TMG was also able to do that, but it's no longer supported. There are also, of course, several solutions available for Linux systems.

Comment: thank you su much, I couldnt try it yet but hope it will work.